# ROS kinetic packages missing in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looking at the ROS binary package files, considerable amount of ROS packages are missing in ubuntu 16.04 (compared to 15.04)

http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/dists/vivid/main/binary-amd64/Packages
http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages

Ubuntu Vivid 15.04 had 926 ROS jade packages and ubuntu Xenial 16.04 only has 548 packages.
Following are some missing packages of interest.

- ros--object-recognition-linemod
- ros--object-recognition-renderer
- ros--object-recognition-tabletop
- ros--moveit-*  - 16 packages
- ros--arbotix-*
- ros--dynamixel-*

Not sure if this removal (and possible merge) of packages is intended.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/238839/ros-kinetic-packages-missing-in-ubuntu-16.04/) by [rajendrant](https://answers.ros.org/users/27398/rajendrant/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2016-07-05

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Not all packages have been released yet for kinetic. Most of the probably will within the next few months.

Those packages are, afaik, all not maintained by OSRF, so it is up to the various maintainers to release them.
Alternative could be to try to install them from source.

You can check on [this page](http://repositories.ros.org/status_page/ros_kinetic_default.html) what packages are currently released for kinetic.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2016-07-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rajendrant](https://answers.ros.org/users/27398/rajendrant/) on 2016-07-11**:
I see, thanks. It would be more informative if this was mentioned in the install wiki - Debian wiki shows up a caution message. But http://www.ros.org/install/ recommends kinetic for latest, and there is no caution message in ubuntu wiki http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation/Ubuntu

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-07-11**:
I agree this could be given some emphasis, but it's also partly common sense (imho): new releases of Ubuntu / Debian / Fedora also don't all immediately come with the full set of packages that earlier versions included. The same holds for ROS.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just started working with ROS again and went straight for Kinetic on Ubuntu 16.04, it is recommended, it is LTS and new intel processors need 16.04 to run.

So i am also shocked and surprised at the number of core packages that do now have binaries to download for Kinetic.

Moveit is one of the major ones, besides isn't Moveit created and supported by OSRF?

---

Originally posted by [Curt](https://answers.ros.org/users/12666/curt/) with karma: 26 on 2016-07-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-07-14**:
The MoveIt developers have not yet released MoveIt for Kinetic. If this is a problem for you, you should contact the MoveIt developers on their mailing list or their bug tracker. MoveIt not maintained by OSRF.